# SQL: How do I limit results to those with the earliest start_date where the end_date is null?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table with the following columns:

> ref_year, ref_no, inv_id, start_date, end_date

The first two columns (ref_year and ref_no) combine to form a primary key in other tables and I will refer to them as 'reference' from now on, but in this table they can appear multiple times. The third (inv_id) is a foreign key. The final two columns represent the date an inv_id became attached to the reference and, where appropriate, the date it ceased being attached to that reference.

I want to return **exactly one row for each reference** that will relfect the earliest inv_id attached to that reference where **end_date is null**. It's the end_date part that's causing me problems. Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    involvements t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    involvements t2
    ON
        (t1.ref_year = t2.ref_year
    AND
        t1.ref_no = t2.ref_no
    AND
        t1.start_date < t2.start_date)
WHERE
    t2.ref_year IS NULL
AND
    t2.ref_no IS NULL
```

This selects the inv_id with the earliest start_date perfectly, but I can't figure out how to account for those cases where the inv_id with the earliest start_date has an end_date that is **not** null, in which case I'd want the script to check the next-oldest inv_id for that reference instead, and so on until it returns one with a null end_date. I tried creating a temporary table with only null end_dates then inner joining to this as a sub-query but of course couldn't because the `WHERE` clause came before the sub-query. Is there an efficient way to get my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ROW_NUMBER() to pick the earliest record for each reference.

```
WITH
  sequenced_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ref_year, ref_no ORDER BY start_date ASC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    involvements
  WHERE
    end_date IS NULL
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

If a reference doesn't have any records where `end_date IS NULL`, then it won't return anything for that reference.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. It's returning a 936Error in SQL Developer for a missing expression in line 7 (the asterisk?). I can't think why it would do so, any ideas?

Comment: @cms_mgr : To test if it really is the `*`, replace it with `ref_year, ref_no, inv_id, start_date, end_date` and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry I should have thought of that myself, perfect now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
(SELECT
    ref_year, 
    ref_no,
    min(start_date) start_date
FROM
    involvements t1
where
    end_date is null
GROUP BY
    ref_year,
    ref_no
) as subq
INNER JOIN involvements t2 on 
    t2.ref_year - subq.ref_year 
    and t2.ref_no = subq.ref_no 
    and subq.start_date = t2.start_date
```